# Cannot add or update a child row in MYSQL, constraint key fails

Tags: mysql

I'm having a little problem when I'm trying to add foreign key to one table that references another but it fail. I have check that the id is exist in the parent table.Someone here can explain me why I'm getting this error?Here is the error

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rsystem`.`tenants_address`, CONSTRAINT `tenants_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`tenants_id`) REFERENCES `tenants` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Table Tenants

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name     | varchar     | NO   |     |         |                |
| Gender   | varchar     | NO   |     |         |                |
| Email    | varchar     | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table tenants_address

```
 +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Street   | varchar     | NO   |     |         |                |
| Postcode | varchar     | NO   |     |         |                |
| Tenants_Id  int        | NO   |     |         |foreign key(tenants)
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have accidently inserted a row into table 1 before the creation of foreign key in table 2, then you might get a foreign key constraint error, since the auto increment value is 2 in table 1 while it is 1 in table 2. To solve this issue you will have to truncate the entire table 1 and set the auto increment value  to 1. Then you can add table 2 as usual.

Comment: Ya I know, I have check it twice, the id already exists in the parent table.